# Android studio can't show icon after changing icon

Tags: android

I have tried to change the default icon into another icon. But, the icon showed in the android is different with the icon at `mipmap` folder.

This is my emulator along with the wrong icon.

[image]

In the android phone, the icon doesn't even appear at all.

This is the manifest file.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

The icon name is right as the code above. How can this happen?

Comment: if there is any folder  similar name to mipmap-anydpi-v26  then delete that folder

Comment: you mean like mipmap-hdpi or something?

Comment: no , mipmap-hdpi is fine . When you create a new project there will be a folder with name `mipmap-anydpi-v26` . If its there then remove the icons from it

Comment: by any chance are you testing on android  7.1 and  +?

Comment: i test on emulator. custom phone 8 api 26

Comment: @Redman thanks, it works now.

Comment: ok let me post an answer for future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new project there will be a folder with name `mipmap-anydpi-v26` . If its there then the icons will be picked from it for devices with Api 26+ . Just delete this folder and app icons will will be picked from mipmap folder .

`mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder is for implementation of [adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) introduced in Api 26 . If you want to use adaptive icon then create an adaptive icon . If your phone is above version 8.0 , adaptive icon will be picked  else normal icon will be picked .

additional if you have `ic_launcher_round` then only phones with version 7.1 will pick from it .

Answer (score 3):

Go to File > New > Image Asset and It will show you below dialog.

[image]

In Icon type select **Launcher Icons (Adaptive and Legacy)** option.

In Asset Type select **Image** and from below path choose your image, Similarly you can select background layer.

Now Select Next and Finish, and your Icon will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've updated the `ic_launcher` image in **every mipmap folder** such as

- mipmap-hdpi
- mipmap-mdpi
- mipmap-xhdpi

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app from the emulator? Sometimes I have to do this for it to update.

Answer (score 0):

try to rename your image file in mipmap as "appicon" and then set it to manifest as

```
   android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
```